# rotate() moves the center of the image away from the cursor

Tags: html, css

[Video with the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JexSFoqjkfU)

This is JSFiddle code:

1. This works well, the center of the image is located in the cursor

```css
#button {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="button" src="https://s3.envato.com/files/274494335/01.jpg" widht="100" height="100" />
  </body>
  <script>
    let moveitem = document.getElementById('button');
    const MoveButton = (e) => {
      moveitem.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
      moveitem.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', MoveButton);
  </script>
</html>
```

2. This does not work as I need, the picture is shifted to the right-down from the cursor and rotates separately, I need the picture to rotate in the cursor

```css
#button {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="button" src="https://s3.envato.com/files/274494335/01.jpg" widht="100" height="100" />
  </body>
  <script>
    let moveitem = document.getElementById('button');
    const MoveButton = (e) => {
      moveitem.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
      moveitem.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', MoveButton);
  </script>
</html>
```

How do I fix this using css only?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Can’t answer this because it’s just been closed but…

Applying the `rotaion` animation overrides the transform applied the `#enterbutton`, so the `translate(-50%, -50%)` is no longer being applied.

Update the `rotaion` animation to:
```
    @keyframes rotation {
        from {
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
           transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);    
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sam Thank you, it worked. I have fixed the issue, and as soon as it becomes open again, please write the answer in a separate message so that I can choose it as a solution to the problem.

Comment: @lzrdblzzrd No problem, I’m glad it worked for you! and thank you, I will submit an answer once it’s reopened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties applied by a keyframe animation will override any previously set.

In your case, applying the rotation animation overrides the `transform` applied to the `#button`. So `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is replaced with `transform: rotate(0deg);`.

To fix the issue, update the rotation animation to include the translate:

```
@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Others had mentioned that the issue was caused by the `transform-origin`, although that is not the case, I would recommend explicitly setting `transform-origin: center center;` in `#button`.

Answer (score -2):

Set the transform origin to center.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: No, it doesn't work. transform-origin rotates the image around the specified point, but does not move the center of the image to the cursor.

Comment: Did you try to put it both in the keyframe and the css selector itself?